# Responsive Div Layout Rearrangement

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I've been working independently on designing a website for a local company and I've been stuck on how to make my layout/design to work responsively. As of right now, my content looks similar to this:

[image: Main Layout/For larger resolutions]

However, as the browser screen decreases, or if the browser is already on a smaller resolution, Item 3 would shift below both Item 1 and Item 2 with a width of 100%. While both Item 1 and Item 2 would be inline with each other. Much like this:

[image: Second Layout/As screen resolution decreases]

Initially, I had both wrapping divs (1 and 2) set to `display: inline-block`. But I couldn't find any sort of research that said that (after changing inline-block div container 2 in a respective media query) a child element could be inline with a separate element while another child element in the same container would not. Recently, I've started debating the use of `display: table` , `display: table-row` , and `display: table-cell` to try and organize content in a table-like layout, but I couldn't find a way to assign Item 1 and Item 2 into their own row while excluding Item 3.

Honestly it's been a while since I've had to mess with anything HTML/CSS/JavaScript/etc., so I'm a little rusty. I'm hoping to see if anyone can point me in the right direction or give me some insight. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a reason not to use floats? It seems like the ideal moment to use them.

Comment: @m69 I've just generally formed a habit of not using floats (mainly from always reading it's a better habit to use newer techniques) when I can and use inline-block or other techniques to align my content. However, in this case I realize they are the most logical choice for what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used fluid design with basic div's you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/74x5975j/6/

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="box-1">BOX 1</div>
    <div class="box-2">BOX 2</div>
    <div class="box-3">BOX 3</div>
</div>
```

here is the CSS with media query:

```
.group {
width: 600px;
height: 300px;    

}
.box-1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    float: left; 
}
.box-2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;    
}

.box-3 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;    
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px){
.group {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;    
}
.box-1 {
    height: 66.666%;
}
.box-2 {
    height: 66.666%;  
}

.box-3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33.333%;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I just didn't think of floats (most likely due to trying to avoid them when I can).